# Run Maven Plugin as a separate process

Tags: java, maven, classpath, maven-plugin

I have written a maven plugin that needs to dynamically add a dependency to is classpath. It scans all jars of the module executing the plugin for ones containing a specific resource and then adds that jar to the classpath.

All worked well when there was one module using this plugin in a project, but I have now added a second module. This classpath still now has the jar from the first time the plugin ran as it is part of the same process.

Is there a way of running a maven plugin as a seperate procccess or isolating the classpath to a plugin some other way

Comment: Can you explain that more in detail what kind of purpose you have with this plugin and what kind of problem you are solving? Cause my first thought is: dynamically adding dependencies sounds like a bad idea...Furthermore have you a project where a real use case can be shown ?

Comment: Its a plugin to generate docs describing an API wrapping java bean's. The beans are split across multiple different jars and are all dependencies of another module, where the plugin to generate the docs is used. The plugin has to go there because one jar of beans effect's the docs produced the by the other, so it is not possible to produce the docs separately for each jar and merge them, and what jars are present will differ in each module the plugin is used/

Comment: Still that doesn't say anything why do you need to add dependencies dynamically. If it is a plugin - and you want it to generate documents for all dependencies - I don't see an issue. If you need to dynamically include or exclude some dependencies - you can add that to configuration of the module.

Comment: There is a way to run plugin in a separate process, it's called *forking*. Please see [maven-surefire-plugin] as an example http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html